# Snowflake unable to cluster table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User...)

---

> I am having table with 88 million rows and applied clustering on date
>   [having 28 distinct values] but when i checked clustering info and
>   clustering depth , snowflake putting all data in single partition and
>   clustering ratio is zero. I followed snowflake documentation for
>   creating clustered table and inserted data into table. What can be the
>   issue ? Any step i missed which is not part of documentation ? Do we
>   need to enable clustering at account level ?

---

***A recent recommendation:***

> For customers that predated automatic clustering, you must manually
>   enable reclustering with `alter table t1 resume recluster;` otherwise
>   reclustering is enabled simply by setting the cluster key.
>
> First, check the column `AUTO_CLUSTERING_ON` from `SHOW TABLES`;
>
> Next, check for results under `AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING_HISTORY()`;

---

Any other recommendations or innovative, "outside-of-the-box" solutions?? Thanks!

Comment: Hey there! I fear your current activities are going to end in an account posting ban as you are posting a lot of content that’s not a great fit for Stack Overflow. Please don’t “seed” content on snowflake here. Can you please first read [our software support on Stack Overflow FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community) before you continue? I’ve also asked the Community Managers team to reach out to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to ask your account SE to turn on auto-clustering for your account. Especially if you don't see any action in the clustering history view.

```
select * from  "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING_HISTORY";
```

You can verify this by looking for the 'automatic_clustering' warehouse on your account under 'billing and usage', assuming you have ACCOUNTADMIN role access. If you don't see this special internal warehouse, chances are it's not turned on.

[AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLOtX.png)

If you already tried to resume recluster and it's still off, chances are it's not on at the account level.

On a side note 88m rows shouldn't be enough to want to cluster, but I guess it depends on your churn or updating. You can always create table as and order your data yourself, to see if you get better partition elimination.

[Create Table with new order](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html):

```
create table newtable as select * from oldtable order by date;
```

[check the partition count with](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_information.html):

```
select system$clustering_information('tablename','(date)');
```